# Apache running on CentOS in VirtualBox is not accessible from host machine

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualbox

I am running CentOS in Virtualbox environment on my Win7 machine. I am **able to connect there by SSH** from host machine (win7), but Apache's httpd is not answering.

I can get response in CentOS by `curl localhost`, `curl 172.27.59.38`, but IP address doesn't respond on host machine:

```
C:\Users\username>telnet 172.27.59.38 80
Connecting To 172.27.59.38...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80:
Connect failed
```

Also `nmap localhost` doesn't show that 80 port is open.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have sudo rights, try running `service httpd status` and see if the server is running.

If you find that apache is running, your problem is probably going to be port related- in which case, running `system-config-securitylevel-tui` will bring up a terminal version of the firewall-management console, which you can then go into and enable the necessary port forwards.

If you find that you *still* cannot access your httpd server, make sure you've opened/forwarded the ports on your router.

Comment: You're AWESOME! Thanks! Only thing utility called system-config-firewall-tui. Thanks again!